# I got a mail with confirmation of received payment and invoice id but no records for that id in admin in magento 1.6.2.0 community version

Tags: magento, paypal

I have a magento store as it was working gud but suddenly i saw a problem related to order as i got mail that i have received a payment for a order and i can see the invoice id in mail but when i checked in admin no record for that order so please suggest what's wrong here other orders are visible but this one order not visible and i have checked in database in sales_flat_order table increment_id, i got 200011821 invoice id but not 200011820(this is the invoice id that i got in received mail).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it's live site so quick help will be appreciable!

Comment: are you using paypal ??

Comment: yes i m using paypal.

Comment: so is your paypal capturing the orders..if paypal is capturing orders have you made sure that magento is set to capture payments as well

Comment: yes, actually all other order's were perfect i mean there was no problem. only in this order i have seen this type of problem.